# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'index') in nextJs

Tags: typescript, next.js, runtime-error, next.js13, nextui

I am Facing this error sometimes when I change the value of the autocomplete box in header component.I have tried updating nextjs version which didn't worked.

Error Reference Image : https://prnt.sc/EnRHlZ3g0HK3

```
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { MagnifyingGlassIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/solid";
import "react-date-range/dist/styles.css"; // main style file
import "react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css"; // theme css file
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import {
  Autocomplete,
  AutocompleteItem
} from "@nextui-org/react";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import { useAsyncList } from "@react-stately/data";

interface UrlParams {
  startDate?: string;
  endDate?: string;
  title?: string;
  location?: string;
}

type ArticleInfoModel = {
  articleName: string;
};

const Header = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const urlParams = useSearchParams();

  const search = () => {
    const params: UrlParams = {};

    if (searchInput.length > 0) {
      params.title = searchInput;
    }

    // @ts-ignore
    const paramString = new URLSearchParams(params).toString();
    const finalURL = `/search?${paramString}`;
    router.push(finalURL);
    setSearchInput(searchInput);
  };

  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState(
    urlParams.get("title") !== undefined && urlParams.get("title") !== null
      ? urlParams.get("title")!
      : ""
  );

  let articleList = useAsyncList<ArticleInfoModel>({
    async load({ signal, filterText }) {
      if (filterText?.length == 0) {
        filterText = searchInput ?? "";
      }
      let res = await fetch(
        `https://api.endpoint?nameStartsWith=${filterText}`,
        { signal }
      );
      let json = await res.json();

      //add label for mapping in autocomplete box
      const filteredArray = json.map((item: any) => {
        return { articleName: item };
      });

      return {
        items: filteredArray,
      };
    },
  });

  return (
    <>
      <header className="sticky top-0 z-50 sm:grid grid-cols-4 bg-white shadow-md py-5 px-5 md:px-10">
        <div className="flex col-span-2 z-50 items-center border-2 rounded-full py-2 md:shadow-sm relative">
          <div className='relative z-50 w-full xl:w-2/3 mr-1 md:mr-0"'>
            <Autocomplete
              inputProps={{
                classNames: {
                  inputWrapper:
                    "h-[30px] bg-transparent shadow-none data-[hover=true]:bg-white group-data-[focus=true]:bg-white",
                },
              }}
              inputValue={articleList.filterText}
              isLoading={articleList.isLoading}
              items={articleList.items}
              onSelectionChange={(key) =>
                setSearchInput(key !== null ? key.toString() : "")
              }
              defaultItems={[{ articleName: searchInput }]}
              defaultSelectedKey={searchInput}
              placeholder={
                searchInput.length > 0 ? searchInput : "Wonach suchst du?"
              }
              onInputChange={articleList.setFilterText}
            >
              {(item) => (
                <AutocompleteItem key={item.articleName} className="capitalize">
                  {item.articleName}
                </AutocompleteItem>
              )}
            </Autocomplete>
            <MagnifyingGlassIcon
              onClick={() => search()}
              className="hidden md:inline-flex min-w-auto h-8 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded-full p-2 cursor-pointer md:mx-2"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <ToastContainer />
      </header>
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Error Log Details are following

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'index')

Call Stack
eval
node_modules\@react-stately\list\dist\import.mjs (142:0)
commitHookEffectListMount
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (20904:0)
commitHookPassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (22957:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23062:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23173:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23173:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23173:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23059:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23173:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23173:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23059:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23173:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23059:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23173:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23059:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23059:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23059:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23173:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23059:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23059:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23173:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23173:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23059:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23173:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23173:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23173:0)
recursivelyTraversePassiveMountEffects
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23040:0)
commitPassiveMountOnFiber
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (23173:0)
```

API Response when 'test' value was passed during API call

```
[
    "test",
    "test 4",
    "test 3 update again",
    "Tester",
    "Testing",
    "Testbox"
]
```

How can we resolve or catch the issue, I am not getting any other error logs except that one which I have shared.
The error should not occur when user search multiple times. And it rarely occurs when we search too many times (i.e. 10-15 times in a minute)